# How Do I make this JQuery window have a minimum size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I've been following this jquery demo in order to make a window appear on my webpage.  The demo can be found here:  http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-message

And the window I am trying to create looks like the following: [image]

You'll notice that the window appears over the actual webpage with the option to press the x or the okay button to go back to the actual webpage.  I want to replace the look and content of the window with my own, while keeping the x and okay button functionality.  I've been looking through some of the files and have been having some problems changing the width of the window.  My question is how do I set the width of the window height in terms of percentage of the screen size or pixel count?  I want to have a strict window size so that it'll fit the requirements of what I'm trying to do.  I've been having a hard time getting this to work.

Here is the source code:
[image]

Since I took a screenshot of the code, you can also find the complete source code through this link:http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-message

I looked through some of the dependency files like jquery.js and jquery-ui.js but I wasn't able to find the line of code I need to change to assert a specific and unchangeable width for the window.  I also looked in the .css file but didn't find any luck there. If anyone knew how to do this i would greatly appreciate it.  Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-width

Comment: That looks pretty useful. I will investigate.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
  width: 500
});
```

This should set your specific width upon initialization. The jQuery UI API reference has all of the available options for this widget http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: Thanks for the help!  Where do I find that code? I'm assuming its in my jquery-ui.js.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. There is a "dialog" object that controls this. You can find this section of code by looking for the text "jQuery UI Dialog" (it may be on differing lines based on which version and customization you may have on the file). Relevant functions in that object will be _size, options, and open

Answer (score 0):

You could download jquery-ui.js file and put it in your own code repository.

Then you could customize it as per your own requirement.

You could pass parameter in the jquery code as :

```
$(function() {
$( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
  modal: true,
  width : <custom value i.e., 400>,
  buttons: {
    Ok: function() {
      $( this ).dialog( "close" );
    }
  }
});
```

});

You could update width, minWidth & minHeight attributes from that js file then.

```
var dialog = $.widget( "ui.dialog", {
version: "1.11.4",
options: {
    appendTo: "body",
    autoOpen: true,
    buttons: [],
    closeOnEscape: true,
    closeText: "Close",
    dialogClass: "",
    draggable: true,
    hide: null,
    height: "auto",
    maxHeight: null,
    maxWidth: null,
    minHeight: 150,
    minWidth: 150,
    modal: false,
    position: {
        my: "center",
        at: "center",
        of: window,
        collision: "fit",
        // Ensure the titlebar is always visible
        using: function( pos ) {
            var topOffset = $( this ).css( pos ).offset().top;
            if ( topOffset < 0 ) {
                $( this ).css( "top", pos.top - topOffset );
            }
        }
    },
    resizable: true,
    show: null,
    title: null,
    width: 500,
```

width attribute is at line no 8138 in the standard downloaded file.

Another way is to add a css class and define width, height parameters there and include that in addClass('') properties of widget creation in js file.